# What are the definitive rules for Windows 8 Screen Scaling

Tags: windows, windows-8, scaling, start-screen

I have a laptop + external screen multi-mon setup running windows 8.

- The laptop has a 15.4 Inch 1920*1080 Screen (Smaller Physical / Higher Pixel Density)
- The Monitor has a 22 Inch 1680*1050 Screen (Larger Physical / Lower Pixel Density)

When I open the start-screen in the laptop, it only shows 5 tile icons high whereas when I open the start-screen on the monitor, it shows 6 tile icons on the vertical. This is extremely counter intuitive to me. As you can see in the screen cap below, it appears that the OS realises something about the physical dimensions or pixel density of the screen as well as the pixel ratio and scales the tiles based on that. (Showing more information on the screen with less vertical pixels)

However I can't find any documentation online on this behavior. Anything I've found just refers to pixel ratio. Can anyone share any definitive info on this behavior?

[image: Start Screen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is explained in the Microsoft article [Scaling to different screens](https://web.archive.org/web/20151201195134/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/b8/archive/2012/03/21/scaling-to-different-screens.aspx),
section "Different pixel densities" :

> Basically, the pixel density is the number of pixels in a physical
> area. This is commonly described as dots per inch, or DPI. As the
> pixel density increases, the physical size of fixed pixels decreases.
>
> As the pixel density increases, the physical size of objects on screen
> gets smaller. If Windows wasn’t built to accommodate different pixel
> densities, objects on screen would be too small to easily tap or read
> on these tablets.
>
> For example, the 140% scale is optimized for
> 1920x1080 HD tablets, which has 140% of the baseline tablet resolution
> of 1366x768.

As you have noted in your post, the laptop has higher pixel density.
Windows 8 then probably applies the 140% rule and so only has enough screen real-estate
for 5 rows. The monitor, having a lower pixel density, apparently displays at 100%.

Comment: Excellent Article harry... exactly what I was looking for. 
My google-fu was obviously failing me. Thanks.